# file permissions - correct ntfs mount option

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I want to mount my NTFS partition to have the same permission as my files and folders in Linux. I have the current mount options:

```
UUID=4C4EF1264EF1098A /run/media/user/FILES ntfs-3g defaults,exec,permissions,inherit,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=022,fmask=133 0 0
```

The problem is, I was not able to execute anything on that partition. What should I be using?

Answer (score 0):

It's about `fmask=133`. The digit `1` applies to the owner's permissions and masks `x` permission, so no file will be executable.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/429858/693277) is useful (it talks about `vfat` but `umask`, `fmask` and `dmask` mechanism is the same). From therein:

> It works as the normal octal permissions but subtracted from 7, and use the absolute value. for instance if you want to set the permissions to `0777` you will need to set it `0000` in the `umask` (e.g. `umask=0000`), if you want to set it to `0755` you will set it to `0022`.

`fmask=133` sets files permissions to `644`. **Use `fmask=022`** or `fmask=033`. I think the last two digits shouldn't really matter because `ntfs-3g` is [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)-based and as such it makes the filesystem available only to the owner (specified by `uid=`), unless you configure and use `allow_other` option.