# Not able to write on samba server

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, samba, raspbian

So, I've been doing a ton of research trying to solve this, and several hours later, I'm absolutely stuck.

I know this has something to do with permissions, but I have absolutely no clue on how to fix it. I can read my samba server from both a Windows 10 box and by Ubuntu 17.10 box. The samba server is running on a Raspberry Pi 3, which is running the latest version of Raspbian Lite, (which in case you didn't know, is basically really light Debian Stretch). I have a test hard drive in it (which is just a USB drive) on `/dev/sda1`, and my share folder in `/media/USBHDD/share`.

So, I'm going to dump the `smb.conf` files and the perms for my media directories in the hope that one of you can help me make some sense out of this.

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = WORKGROUP

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
#   wins support = no

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
   dns proxy = no

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes
security = user


#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
   syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.  
   passdb backend = tdbsam

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
   map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
;   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
   usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
   read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# The following parameter makes sure that only "username" can connect
# to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin


[share]
comment = Pi shared folder
path = /media/USBHDD/share
browseable = yes
read only = no
create mask 0660
directory mask = 0771
valid users = backups MYUSERNAME root
force user = MYUSERNAME
```

The output of `ls -l` in my `/media/USBHDD/share` is:

```
rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 16384 Dec 30 20:21 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 16384 Dec 30 20:21 Miscellaneous
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 16384 Dec 30 20:21 Pictures
```

Also, in case you need the `ls -l` for `share/`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 16384 Dec 30 20:21 share
```

Thanks for reading through this. I appreciate any and all help I can get.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that /dev/sda1 is an NTFS formatted drive, as it is being accessed by windows machines. That makes chown and chmod unable to work.

Comment: Only the owner of the directories can write to them....Give everyone write permissions.  Your directory and file mask is also incorrect.  Your configuration file explains this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> I forgot to mention that the drive in `/media/USBHDD/shares` is formatted in NTFS, to be readable on windows. That makes it unable to be changed using `chown` and `chmod`, which are both solutions that I've already tried.

I guess you're using `ntfs-3g`. In this case you should research the following mount options of it: `uid`,`gid`,`dmask`,`fmask`. First thing you should do is passing `uid=MYUSERNAME` to whatever mechanism mounts the drive. This will make the filesystem appear as if everything in it belonged to `MYUSERNAME`.

If you were mounting via `fstab`, the proper line would look similar to [the one in this question](https://superuser.com/q/1271534/432690) (but read my answer there). The path `/media/…` suggests the drive might be mounted by some sort of automounter; if so, then you should configure its options.

Some parts of my original answer (below) apply to filesystems that support UNIX permissions. With NTFS, instead of `chown` you should just pass proper `uid` and `gid` while mounting.

---

Original answer:

Your share and objects under it are owned by `root` and only the owner has write permissions. I'm talking about UNIX permissions in `ls -l` output, this itself has nothing to do with Samba.

Then Samba forces any valid user (`valid users = backups MYUSERNAME root`; these are Samba users, not necessarily UNIX users) to be `MYUSERNAME` (`force user = MYUSERNAME`) in context of UNIX permissions. This user has no write access.

Possible solutions:

- let `MYUSERNAME` own everything in the share:

  ```
  sudo chown -R MYUSERNAME: /media/USBHDD/share
  ```
- give every user write access to everything in the share:

  ```
  sudo chmod -R +w /media/USBHDD/share
  ```
- a combination of above, with reduced scope maybe; or a solution that uses group access; now you know what the issue is, so ask yourself what permissions to what asset you want to give to whom.
- `force user = root` (if possible), but this would be stupid.

Some of these solutions will work better with different `create mask` and `directory mask` in Samba configuration. [Research](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) and understand their meaning.

Comment: The correct solution is to change the default owner, authenticate as that user, when you mount the drive.  Be sure the permission masks are correct.  Reading the Samba documentation is a great start

Comment: I forgot to mention that the drive in /media/USBHDD/shares is formatted in NTFS, to be readable on windows. That makes it unable to be changed using chown and chmod, which are both solutions that I've already tried. Thanks for the answer though, I appreciate the response.

Comment: @GarrukApex I have expanded my answer.