# How can I create and edit files from a Windows file share on Linux (CentOS)?

Tags: linux, mount, file-permissions, smb, cifs

I have a Windows shared drive that I have mounted on my CentOS 7 machine using the [instructions by Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/448263) that I would now like to create and edit files on. However I must be elevated to create and edit files on any folder on the drive. I have tried using `chmod` to allow all users access, but to no avail, and have even tried unmounting/remounting the drive.

How can I get non-elevated access to the drive?

(I am creating these files using Matlab, and Matlab can't be run via `sudo`, so simply staying elevated is not an option).

#### Terminal Printout

```
[millironx@mymachine ~]$ sudo umount /mnt
[millironx@mymachine ~]$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=millironx,password=mypassword,domain=AD //files.example.com/shared /mnt
[millironx@mymachine ~]$ cd /mnt/matlab-program
[millironx@mymachine matlab-program]$ touch testfile
touch: cannot touch 'testfile': Permission denied
[millironx@mymachine matlab-program]$ sudo chmod +rwx /mnt/matlab-program
[millironx@mymachine matlab-program]$ touch testfile
touch: cannot touch 'testfile': Permission denied
[millironx@mymachine matlab-program]$ sudo touch testfile
[millironx@mymachine matlab-program]$ ls
testfile
[millironx@mymachine matlab-program]$ rm testfile
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file 'testfile`? y
rm: cannot remove 'testfile': Permission denied
[millironx@mymachine matlab-program]$ sudo rm testfile
[millironx@mymachine matlab-program]$ sudo matlab
sudo: matlab: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `uid=` and maybe `gid=` mount option. See [`man 8 mount.cifs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs):

> `uid=arg`
>   sets the uid that will own all files or directories on the mounted filesystem when the server does not provide ownership information. It may be specified as either a username or a numeric uid. When not specified, the default is uid `0`. The `mount.cifs` helper must be at version 1.10 or higher to support specifying the uid in non-numeric form. See the section on File And Directory Ownership And Permissions below for more information.
>
> `gid=arg`
>   sets the gid that will own all files or directories on the mounted filesystem when the server does not provide ownership information. It may be specified as either a groupname or a numeric gid. When not specified, the default is gid `0`. The `mount.cifs` helper must be at version 1.10 or higher to support specifying the gid in non-numeric form. See the section on File And Directory Ownership And Permissions below for more information.
>
> […]
>
> File And Directory Ownership And Permissions
>   The core CIFS protocol does not provide unix ownership information or mode for files and directories. Because of this, files and directories will generally appear to be owned by whatever values the `uid=` or `gid=` options are set, and will have permissions set to the default `file_mode` and `dir_mode` for the mount. Attempting to change these values via `chmod`/`chown` will return success but have no effect.
>   […]

This section also mentions a scenario where "the client and server negotiate unix extensions" and a scenario where "it's also possible to emulate them locally on the server" etc.

In your case simple `uid=` and `gid=` should suffice. Note they specify Unix user and group, `uid=` and `username=` are different and in general may take different values.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o uid=millironx,gid=users,username=millironx,password=mypassword,domain=AD //files.example.com/shared /mnt
```

<sub>You may also find [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1271534/432690) useful.</sub>